# How to integrate facebook login to multiple Android packages through one Facebook app?

Tags: android, facebook

We have multiple versions of our game for Android devices (free, paid, f2p, for different stores, for different devices), each with different package's names.
We want to integrate Facebook Login to these apps. 
And we have one Facebook App, it was launched on Facebook and associated with iOS-apps (there are free, paid and f2p versions too).

The main question is **whether we can provide fb-connection for all these packages through one fb-app**? It's important to use one fb-app due to rank in Facebook App Center and to common integrity.

In App Dashboard one can't set multiple package names for Android App, right? But it seems, that you can set up multiple Key Hashes. So, am i right supposing, that package name used only for deep linking and for opening the  Google Play (or another store) and for providing fb-connect one only needs the Key Hash?

What is the best way for us with multiple packages and one fb-app? What will happen to apps whose package's names will not match with the specified in the dashboard?

Thanks!

Comment: Your assumption is correct, you should be able to use multiple apps/fb app, but deep linking and play store linking will only use the package name set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As we found out and as Ming Li has mentioned in comments, one can add multiple Key Hashes to provide FB-connect feature in multiple Android apps through one FB-app. So login will work.

And if you have set package name  in App Dashboard and have enabled "FB Login" checkbox, then all viral-activity from all connected Apps will redirect to store with this package name.

Comment: I am facing the similar problem. I have a single Facebook app in my Facebook Developer console, that I use for both my iOS and Android apps. I can easily handle callback URLs using the iOS app. But in case of an Android, if the Android device has not installed the Facebook application, my Android app just works fine. But if the Android device has Facebook app installed, then it's giving an error regarding Key Hash to add in the settings. There are multiple iOS and Android apps that I am using. So how can I handle my Android app?\

Comment: What should I enter in Package Name and Class Name fields in the Android section of the app?